# Powershell - Settable NoteProperty

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

In my PowerShell script, I'm creating a custom object with NoteProperties:

```
$foo = New-Object System.Object
$foo | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Something -value [int]dataRow["Field"]
```

But then later in the code, I need to do:

```
$foo.Something = 10
```

On that line, I get the error message

Property 'Something' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At ...
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CoreMajor:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

So I'm guessing NoteProperty is supposed to be settable since the docs say a static value. But then how can I edit/update the property? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 2 remarks. 1) I cannot reproduce your issue, the property `Something` exists and it is settable. 2) Presumably there is a mistake in `-value [int]dataRow["Field"]`. You should use the argument in parenthesis, otherwise the whole argument is treated as a string `[int]dataRow[Field]`, i.e. it is not evaluated as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
$foo | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Something -value [int]dataRow["Field"]
```

with this

```
$foo | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Something -value ([int]$dataRow["Field"])
```

Because of the syntactical error, the property Something was never created in the first place.  You should have gotten an error about that, except if your `$ErrorActionPreference` is set to SilentlyContinue (but then you shouldn't get the 2nd error message either, I guess).